# Unable to use the logout function within the Drawer Navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation-drawer

I am fairly new to react-native but I have been able to make a login with authentication using firebase. Alongside this, I have used a drawer for further navigation. However, when a user is logged in I want them to be able to logout via a button on that drawer. Currently, when I click it is it doing nothing...

I have tried changing to the this.logout function to this.logout() which reaches the console.log("here) statement but then returns an undefined error. I have also played around with the bindings but with no results.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        authenticated: false,
    }
    this.logout = this.logout.bind(this)
};


componentDidMount() {
    firebaseConfig.auth().onAuthStateChanged((authenticated) => {
        authenticated ? this.setState(() => ({
            authenticated: true,
        })) : this.setState(() => ({
            authenticated: false,
        }));
    });
}

//Logout of firebase and navigate to login screen
logout = () => {
    console.log("here")
    firebaseConfig.auth().signOut()
        .then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Login'))
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        });
};


render() {
    //const {currentUser} = this.state
    return (
        <Application/>

    )
    }
}


const DrawerComponents = (props) =>
<SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea}>
    <View style={styles.logo}>
    </View>
    <ScrollView>
        <DrawerItems{...props}/>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <Button title="Logout" onPress={this.logout}/>
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
</SafeAreaView>


const TabNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
Home: {screen: Homepage},
Profile: {screen: Profile},
Login: {
screen: Login,
navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
            return {
                drawerLabel: () => null,
                drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed'
            }
        }
    },
    SignUp: {
        screen: SignUp,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
            return {
                drawerLabel: () => null,
                drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed'
            }
        }
    },
    Loading: {
        screen: Loading,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
            return {
                drawerLabel: () => null,
                drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed'
            }
        }
    },
},

{
    headerMode: null,
    contentComponent: DrawerComponents,
    drawerWidth: WIDTH,
    drawerPosition: "right",
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    contentOptions: {
        activeTintColor: "orange"
    }

});

const Application = createAppContainer(TabNavigator)
});
```

I am expecting that upon clicking logout, the currently logged in user on firebase is signed out and then is redirected to the login screen.

Comment: Can you have this running in expo.io ?

Comment: Also you don't have to bind an arrow function.

Comment: Changed the bind arrow but still nothing unfortuntely.